# Sitecore 8.1 : SessionEndPipeline failed

Tags: sitecore, analytics, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

While going through the log files (of sitecore) I noticed more than 2K error entries for below. It's on CD server but the site seems to be running OK. I googled to see if anyone has faced this issue but no luck.

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: Could not find
>   configuration node: databases/database[@id='master'] Source:
>   Sitecore.Kernel    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetConfigNode(String xpath, Boolean
>   assert)    at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String
>   configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, Boolean
>   assert)    at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(String name,
>   Boolean assert)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(String name)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.get_DefinitionDatabase()    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.VisitEnd.RunRules.Process(VisitEndArgs
>   endArgs)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineMethod.Invoke(Object[] parameters)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs
>   args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.VisitEnd.VisitEndPipeline.Run(VisitEndArgs
>   args)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SessionEnd.RaiseVisitEnd.Process(SessionEndArgs
>   endArgs)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineMethod.Invoke(Object[] parameters)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs
>   args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.EndSession.SessionEndPipeline.Run(SessionEndArgs
>   sessionEndArgs)    at
>   Sitecore.Web.Application.RaiseSessionEndEvent(HttpApplication context)

More info:

1. xDB is disabled.

Appreciate if I can get help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says :

> Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='master']

I ran into same type of error some time ago and it turns out that when you switch your references to master database toward web database on CD server,  any indexing mechanics that uses master database must be turned off. In my case, I checked all config files related to Lucene indexes which somehow pointing to master database, like this:

```
<locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
    <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>master</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore</Root>
    </crawler>
</locations>
```

There are several indexing config files which might use this pattern, including analytics and other extra features. I turned them off and the error disappeared.

Comment: There is a bundled disabled config file called something like '/App_Config/Includes/switchmastertoweb.config.disabled' enable that for your CD nodes, or perhaps just review what it does as there are many references that point to the master db by default.